# Retrieving individual element from xdotool search result with Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

Having trouble with a bash script. I can't figure out how to get the individual pids from the xdotool search function.

Code

```
google-chrome --app=https://google.com &
google-chrome --app=https://google.com &
google-chrome --app=https://google.com &
google-chrome --app=https://google.com &

sleep 5

pids=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --name google)
echo $pids

width=1920
height=1080

for i in 0 1 2 3;
  do
    x=$((((i)/2)*$width))
    y=$(((i%2)*$height))

    echo $x
    echo $y
    echo "${pids[$i]}"

    #xdotool windowmove ${pids[i]} $x $y
  done
```

Output

```
46137345 46137352 46137355 46137358
0
0
46137345
46137352
46137355
46137358
0
1080

1920
0

1920
1080
```

I can't see a `/n` in the string which is what I thought was doing it so don't know why it's making the new lines.

I'm very new to bash scripting so I have no doubt it's something stupid obvious.

I'm using bash version 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `pids` variable is just a string but you're trying to treat it like an array.

Use an outer set of parens to make pids an array as in:

```
pids=($(xdotool search --onlyvisible --name google))

$ for i in "${pids[@]}"; do echo $i; done
46137345
46137352
46137355
46137358
```